# Do "things" that are present depend on Dasein?

Tags: time, reality, heidegger, being-and-time

Do "things" that are present depend on Dasein? I have read Being and Time, but a very long time ago. I am not sure if I mean present at hand, but I do mean in general anything that exists in the present moment. I am not sure why anyone would claim that everything that exists in the present moment depends on Dasein, but it seems to make sense if real entities do not have a tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following quote refers to "fully fledged independent objects", i.e. independent of Dasein:

Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy - Heidegger [2.2.2 Modes of Encounter](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heidegger/#ModEnc)

> When Dasein engages in, for example, the practices of natural science,
> when sensing takes place purely in the service of reflective or
> philosophical contemplation, or when philosophers claim to have
> identified certain context-free metaphysical building blocks of the
> universe (e.g., points of pure extension, monads), the entities under
> study are phenomenologically removed from the settings of everyday
> equipmental practice **and are thereby revealed as fully fledged
> independent objects**, that is, as the bearers of certain
> context-general determinate or measurable properties (size in metres,
> weight in kilos etc.). Heidegger calls this mode of Being
> presence-at-hand, and he sometimes refers to present-at-hand entities
> as ‘Things’.

In being present-at-hand these things exist in the present.  However, in authentic temporality Dasein interacts in the present only in *a moment of vision*.  This is the moment in which a formulated action is actually enacted, amongst the present-at-hand.

From Being & Time, ¶ 74· The Basic Constitution of Historicality

> (H.338) Corresponding to the inauthentic future (awaiting), there is a
> special way of Being-*alongside* the things with which one concerns
> oneself. This way of Being-alongside is the Present - the
> "waiting-towards"; ... That *Present* which is held in authentic
> temporality and which thus is *authentic* itself, we call the "*moment
> of vision*". ... as an authentic Present or waiting-towards, the
> moment of vision permits us *to encounter for the first time* what can
> be 'in a time' as ready-to-hand or present-at-hand.

Comment: yeah that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: hang on... so some kind of "first encounter" with something is always dependent on Dasein, but not its e.g. repetition in our life? That would make sense in my life (pseudo philosophical existential cluster duck)

Comment: Any first encounter is where the thing gets defined, e.g. atom.  We define things by the appearance of phenomena.

Comment: OK. Do get in the habit of saying "yes or no" to direct questions. And thanks again. Incidentally, I get then - I think - why inauthentic "demise" is problematic (how many times does your body give up) and authentic demise questionable (it depends on Dasein's temporality)

Comment: Yes, you can think about your demise objectively but obviously you can't experience being dead.  However, Dasein's authentic progression (its handing itself down, or resolute repetition) can reach beyond demise insofar as it takes into consideration its wider network of connection (*Zusammenhang*).

Comment: Yeah demise is a con, but I just think it's a TOTAL con. Kinda cheating, perhaps. But I don't think there is another wiggle room there to say we authentically demise (dependent on temporality). Not unless you want to say there is another type of present that constructs Dasein (vague, but then good arguments don't need ornaments)

Comment: 'Con' seems a bit strong; finitude covers it IMO.

Comment: Finitude of... but I'm being overly pretentious.